# Non zero sections of sheaves which vanish on all fibers

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, fiber-bundles, ringed-spaces

I was stuck on the following question and I was wondering if someone more familiar with sheaf theory might be able to help me with it. $\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a locally ringed space and $\F$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Let $\mathcal{F}_x$ denote the stalk at a point $x \in X$. We define the *fiber* of $\mathcal{F}$ at a point $x \in X$ to be the quotient:
$$Fib(F)_x := \F_x / (\mathfrak{m}_x \mathcal{F}_x)$$
Given an open set $U$ containing $x$ there is a natural evaluation map $Ev_x \colon \F(U) \to Fib(F)_x$.
Now here are my questions:

1. Can you give me an example of a sheaf with the property that there exists a section $s \in \F(U)$ for some open set $U$ such that for all $x \in U$ we have $Ev_x(s) = 0 $ but $s \neq 0$?
2. Are there any natural assumptions I can make to rule out this possibility? For the record, I would like something weaker than 'locally finitely generated and projective'.

Comment: Consider a nilpotent element as a global section of the structure sheaf of the spectrum of a nonreduced ring.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Can you give an example where the structure sheaf does not have this property but the module does?

Comment: I *think* that if the sheaf is flat quasicoherent over a reduced scheme with finitely many irreducible components, it works. Consider in contrast the quasicoherent module $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ over the spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found another example of 1 where the structure sheaf does not have the property.

$\newcommand{\O}{\mathcal{O}}$
Suppose $X$ is a smooth manifold and $\O_X$ is the sheaf of smooth functions on $X$. Let us fix a point $x_0$ and define $\mathcal{E}$ to be the submodule of $\O_X$ which consists of smooth functions which vanish to infinite order at $x_0$. That is, the elements of $\mathcal{E}$ vanish at $x_0$ and all derivatives vanish at $x_0$. This sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ does not yet have the desired property, but let us construct new sheaf.

Let $\mathcal{W}$ be the following sheaf. For an open $U \subset X$:
$$ \mathcal{W}(U) = \begin{cases} 0 & x_0 \notin U \\ \mathcal{E}_{x_0} & x_0 \in U \end{cases} $$
Here $\mathcal{E}_{x_0}$ denotes the stalk of $\mathcal{E}$ at $x_0$. A fairly standard argument shows that $\mathcal{E}_{x_0}/ m_{x_0} \mathcal{E} = 0$. Therefore, any non-zero section of $\mathcal{W}$ has the desired property. So long as $dim (X) > 0$ the sheaf $\mathcal{W}$ is not trivial so we have a counter example.

This example clearly depends on properties of the ring of smooth functions. I am still curious if there exists an example where $\O_X$ is the sheaf of analytic functions on an analytic manifold.

Edit: I made a mistake in the definition of $\mathcal{W}$.

Comment: It is not clear to me, how $\mathcal{W}$ becomes an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. How do I multiply a smooth function $f \in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ ($x_0 \notin U$) with a germ of a function *at* $x_0$?

Comment: I made a mistake in the definition. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Dear @JoelVillatoro, as you said, "This example clearly depends on properties of the ring of smooth functions", can you explain it more concretely?

Comment: I guess I am using the property that the ring of smooth functions admits a submodule $ E $ with the property that the stalk $ E_{x_0} $ is not trivial but $m_{x_0} E = E $. This is in contrast to say, the ring of analytic functions where no such submodule exists.